# Is there a "nicer" way to close applications in Windows other than "taskkill"? (In the terminal.)

Tags: windows, terminal, process, kill

"Kill" sounds kind of harsh, as if I'm KILLING the process with an axe, suddenly, without forewarning, cutting off whatever work it might be doing right away, when I actually just want to send a friendly:

> Kindly stop yourself as soon as possible, dear process, for I am doing some maintenance. I will soon launch you anew!

Reading the manual, I realize that there is a `/F` flag:

> /F                     Specifies to forcefully terminate the process(es).

Maybe the default mode *is* what I describe, and only the `/F` mode does what I fear? Is that how it works?

Answer (score 0):

You wonder if taskkill without /f will terminate the process without running the program's own shutdown routine?

So I started notepad.exe, typed in some text, pressed the x at the top right, and Notepad asked me if I wanted to save changes before closing the program.

I pressed cancel.

I went to terminal, and typed in:

```
taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe"
```

The same question came up as if I had clicked the x. So without /f, you allow the program to run its shutdown routine.

So you understood the /f parameter correctly. Without it, it does it nicely, with /f it forces the termination regardless and skips the programs shutdown routine.

> Maybe the default mode is what I describe, and only the /F mode does what I fear? Is that how it works?

Basically, yes.